# Call validation from another class JAVA

Tags: java, class, validation, joptionpane, stringtokenizer

Im working on a project that has 5 classes. One of which is a validation class. I validated the data in the control class but professor wants it in a separate class. 
here is a sample of my code. User enters information in tokens. Runs fine, but in the controller class i am supposed to "Call" the validation that has a class of its own. How am I supposed to code this?

```
while (tkCustomer.hasMoreTokens()){

    //store each token in the corresponding variable
    //Make sure we format integers
    //variablename = tkCustomer.nextToken();
        firstName = tkCustomer.nextToken( );
        lastName = tkCustomer.nextToken ( ); 
        phone = tkCustomer.nextToken ( );
        nbrVehicle = Integer.parseInt(tkCustomer.nextToken( ));
        nbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(tkCustomer.nextToken( ));
    }

    //validate each data entered here
        int firstNameLength = firstName.length();

        if(firstNameLength == 0){

            String errorMessage = "Please Enter a Valid First Name";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Invalid Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            int lastNameLength = lastName.length();

            if(lastNameLength == 0){

                String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Valid Last Name";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }else{
              int phoneLength = phone.length();

              if(phoneLength != 10) {
                  String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Valid Phone Number";
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Phone Number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                  System.exit(0);
        }else{
            if(nbrVehicle < 1 || nbrVehicle > 10) {
                String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Number Between 1 & 10 for Your Order of Vehicles";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Vehicle Order", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }else{
             if(nbrTanks != 2 && nbrTanks != 4 && nbrTanks != 8 && nbrTanks != 10 && nbrTanks != 15 && nbrTanks != 20){

                 String errorMesssage = "Please Enter Either 2, 4, 8, 10, 15, or 20 for Your Order of Tanks";
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Number of Tanks", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 System.exit(0);

             }
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

ALso, the program crashes once the user selects a certain option that is given to them. the full code for the control class is below. DUring the first round of tokenizer items the program runs fine. After the second round the program crashes giving me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
>       at project3example.HayloFactoryController.main(HayloFactoryController.java:126)

I have tried the "while has more tokens" method but that just sends the program into an endless loop and can only be terminated with the stop button.

here is the full code for the control class:

```
package project3example;
```

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HayloFactoryController {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create variables to hold information collected from the user

    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String phone = "";
    int nbrTanks = 0;
    int nbrVehicle = 0;
    double total = 0;

    do{

        //collect the data entered by the user in 
        //variables
    String customerMessage = "Please enter the following separated by spaces"
            + "\n\n"
            + "- Customer First Name\n"
            + "- Customer Last Name\n"
            + "- Customer Phone\n"
            + "- Number of Vehicles\n"
            + "- Number of Tanks"
            + "\n\n"
            + "Example: Homer Simpson 9094559384 5 8\n\n"
            ;

        StringTokenizer tkCustomer = new StringTokenizer(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(customerMessage));

    while (tkCustomer.hasMoreTokens()){

    //store each token in the corresponding variable
    //Make sure we format integers
    //variablename = tkCustomer.nextToken();
        firstName = tkCustomer.nextToken( );
        lastName = tkCustomer.nextToken ( ); 
        phone = tkCustomer.nextToken ( );
        nbrVehicle = Integer.parseInt(tkCustomer.nextToken( ));
        nbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(tkCustomer.nextToken( ));
    }

    //validate each data entered here
        int firstNameLength = firstName.length();

        if(firstNameLength == 0){

            String errorMessage = "Please Enter a Valid First Name";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Invalid Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            int lastNameLength = lastName.length();

            if(lastNameLength == 0){

                String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Valid Last Name";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }else{
              int phoneLength = phone.length();

              if(phoneLength != 10) {
                  String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Valid Phone Number";
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Phone Number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                  System.exit(0);
        }else{
            if(nbrVehicle < 1 || nbrVehicle > 10) {
                String errorMesssage = "Please Enter a Number Between 1 & 10 for Your Order of Vehicles";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Vehicle Order", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }else{
             if(nbrTanks != 2 && nbrTanks != 4 && nbrTanks != 8 && nbrTanks != 10 && nbrTanks != 15 && nbrTanks != 20){

                 String errorMesssage = "Please Enter Either 2, 4, 8, 10, 15, or 20 for Your Order of Tanks";
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMesssage, "Invalid Number of Tanks", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 System.exit(0);

             }
        }
        }
        }
        }




    //Create a customer Object
    //CustomerObject variableName = new CustomerObject(arguments)
        HayloCustomer customer = new HayloCustomer (firstName, lastName, phone, nbrVehicle, nbrTanks, total);

    //Present the customer with a choice of vehicles
        String[]  choices = {"EV-EX 4", "EV-EX 6", "EV-DX 9", "EV-DX 12", "EV-SX 13"};

    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            null                                        // center over parent
            , "Select a Vehicle type and Number of Fuel Cells"   // message
            , "Vehicle & Fuel Cell Selection"               // title in title bar
            , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION                     // Option type
            , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE                     // messageType
            , null                                          // icon
            , choices                                       // Options
            , "APS 24"                                      // initial value
    );
    //get the selection from the customer
        StringTokenizer tkVehicle= new StringTokenizer(choices[response]);

    //populate the vehicle variables
        String vehicleType;
        int nbrCells;
        int costVehicle;
        int tankCost; 

    //while (tkVehicle.hasMoreTokens());
        vehicleType = tkVehicle.nextToken();
        nbrCells = Integer.parseInt(tkVehicle.nextToken());
        costVehicle = Integer.parseInt(tkVehicle.nextToken());
        tankCost = Integer.parseInt(tkVehicle.nextToken());

    //Create our vehicle object
    //VehicleObject variableName = new VehicleObject(arguments)
        HayloVehicle vehicleFactory = new HayloVehicle(vehicleType, nbrCells, costVehicle, tankCost);

    //Create our factory object
    //FactoryObject factoryVariableName = new FactoryObject(customerObjectVariable, vehicleObjectVariable);
        HayloFactory factory = new HayloFactory(customer, vehicleFactory);

    //ask the object to process the order
    //factoryVariableName.process();

        customer.toString();
        vehicleFactory.toString();
        factory.process();
        factory.toString();

    //write code below to display the result for each order
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, factory.getSummary());

}while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Enter More Orders?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    //write code below to display the summary for all the orders
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, HayloFactory.salesSummary()); 
}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated! Beginner here, with the grade on the line!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to write out a class with your validation logic in a method that takes as its argument a customer object (populate the field from the String Tokenizer) and pass it to the method. The validation can be done in the method and designate some error code/success code to return from the validation and show error or success as applicable. There are many other ways of designing this but this perhaps will be quickest.